# what type do I have to define a column to generate a text area Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a table "Notifications" with the following migration:

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :from
      t.string :to
      t.string :subject
      t.text :content
      t.string :interval_type
      t.integer :interval
      t.datetime :begin
      t.datetime :end
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I go to myapplication/notifications/new I see a input type="text" instead of a text area at the "Content" field.

SOLVED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view file, define the `content` field as a `text_area` instead of a `text_field`.

```
# app/views/notifications/new.html.erb
# Change <%= f.text_field :content %> to <%= f.text_area :content %>
```